# django add to category design

Tags: python, django

I ve got the following models:

```
# models.py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shop = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pizza = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza)
```

With a simple view

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def pizza_view(request):
    pizzas=Pizza.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pizzas.html', {'pizzas':pizzas})
```

and a simple template

```
# pizzas.html

...
    <table>
  {% for pizza in pizzas %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{pizza.name}}</td>
      <td>{{pizza.price}}</td>
      <td>{{pizza.rating}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
     <table>
```

Now I would like to be able to add a topping to a pizza right in this view. What is the Djangoish way to design it? Do I pack the whole table into a form and add a ModelChoiceField to each row and a commit button or do I use multiple forms?
I d like to know, how to design this a proper way, maybe you know some links that help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably any starters tutorial touches this subject. Also there is excellent documentation available at the django site:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Comment: I already did the tutorial and I ve got no problem with implementation of anything. I am missing a design proposal

Comment: A design proposal on **what**? On the way your application look, on how it's architecture is? There are various ways to add a topping to a pizza.